# Attempting to unserialize data not working

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization

I am really going crazy at the moment, i have the following serialized, however when i try to unserialized it returns false.

Serialized array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a:1:{i:0;s:9:"714443801";}
)
```

Current Code:

```
<?php
$votesArray = unserialize($Vzzz);

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($votesArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

?>

Comment: Are you storing the serialized data somewhere and after retrieving you are doing unserialize?

Answer (score 1):

You are not unserializing it:
try:

```
print_r(unserialize($votesArray[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing the serialized string, then store like this:

```
$serialisedData = base64_encode(serialize($arr));
```

After Retrieving,

```
//to unserialize...
$arr = unserialize(base64_decode($serialisedData));
```